# Port 80 not available on macbook localhost

Tags: macos, apache, ports

I am trying to setup my macbook to serve Apache over (localhost) port 80. Here's what I did:

- add line `pass in proto tcp from any to any port 80` to /etc/pf.conf
- reboot
- switch off the firewall
- make sure that httpd.conf listens to port 80 `Listen 80`

It is still giving me "connection refused" in the browser, and port 80 is not showing up on the portscan utility.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration seemed to be messed up because I was trying to run httpd through brew. It ended up giving index pages from different directories. I ended up removing httpd from brew and reverting to the built-in apache.

Apache now listens to port 80